# How to dynamically change sigma.js settings?

Tags: sigma.js

I use sigma.js with `drawLabels:true`.

When I zoom out labels start to overlap with each other, so I want to disable them after `s.camera.ratio` is big enough.

My attempt:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('sigma-mouse')[0]
    .addEventListener("mousewheel", function() {
      console.log(event)
      if (s.camera.ratio > 20) {
          // Set drawLabels to false 
          s.refresh()
      }
}, false);
```

The question is how to set drawLabels to false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the settings with `s.settings('drawLabels', false);`